# mod_wsgi: Reading POSTed file content remains empty

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cgi, wsgi

I don't get it, I don't understand.

In a self-developed Python web framework I'm posting a file form element to the server using JavaScript.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", url, true);
request.send(formData);
```

The server, sporting mod_wsgi, receives the request like so:

```
if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    post_env = environ.copy()
    post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
            environ=post_env,
            keep_blank_values=True)
```

Then, when I want to access the form field's content to save it to a file, the following will return an empty result:

```
form['file'].file.read()
```

(All code has been edited for simplicity)

What puzzles me is that the form field will show the correct file name and MIME type, only `file.read()` remains empty.

Also all other information from other input text fields comes through and is accessible. 
I also checked that `environ['REQUEST_METHOD']` is actually `POST`.

As to HTTP Headers for encoding (such as `multipart/form-data`), I thought that the `XMLHttpRequest` object will take care of that, once `formData.append()` receives a file input as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's the solution:

I can't explain it, but the file form fields get emptied on first read, which I found out by accident. Maybe a bug, who knows.
I assumed that they would stay intact (like any other variable) and can be read multiple times.

What I ignored was that I had in fact addressed them several times.
So the solution was to first store the file's content in a variable, and then use that multiple times.

Comment: can u show the code snippet for the change that you needed? thanks